# Bug in votes left notification

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, notifications

Since the maximum amount of votes went from 30 to 40, there's a small bug in the code showing the yellow "votes left" notification box. When I vote 40 times on a day, I get the following notifications, after:

- 25: 5 votes left
- 35: 5 votes left
- 36: 4 votes left
- etc.

So the notifications have been updated to work with the new limit of 40, except for the "5 votes left" which fires after 25 (incorrect) and 35 (correct) votes.

I've seen this multiple times, so I'm pretty sure it's not a browser glitch or something that would cause it to happen only sometimes.

Comment: confirmed ... odd ... fixing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OOPS .... had a little logic hole there, fixed now. Only happened if you *only* voted on questions.